# Binary data to hex string in PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex

I need to take some binary data and convert it to hex. When I do

```
$value = bin2hex($msg);
```

$value is "0003". However I need it to be a hex string, like 0x0003 or even just "03" (hex), in order to use it.

How can I convert it?

Comment: `$hexString = "0x" . $value`?

Comment: Can you please provide the input value?

Answer (score 2):

I thing you need to convert a string to hex string to use `bin2hex($msg);`
You can use this

```
function strToHex($string){
$hex = '';
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
    $ord = ord($string[$i]);
    $hexCode = dechex($ord);
    $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
}
return strToUpper($hex);}
```

Like This

```
 $value = bin2hex(strToHex($msg));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
  $value = dechex(bindec($msg));
     echo $value ;
```